# Windows Service NullReferenceException C#

Tags: c#, service, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to create a Web API service but when I'm trying to run as service I get `NullReferenceException`. It's working well if I remove the `ServiceBase` part. If I replace the Thread to do nothing, then it's working as usual.

What could be causing the `NullReferenceException`?

```
namespace WebApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //To Debug
             //BuildWebHost(args).Run();

             //To Run as Service 
             using (var service = new TestService())
             {
                ServiceBase.Run(service);
             }
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000");

    }
}
```

```
class TestService : ServiceBase
    {
        public TestService()
        {
            ServiceName = "TestService";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = CheckFileExists();
            File.AppendAllText(filename, $"{DateTime.Now} started.{Environment.NewLine}");            
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program.BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run));
            t.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            string filename = CheckFileExists();
            File.AppendAllText(filename, $"{DateTime.Now} stopped.{Environment.NewLine}");
        }

        private static string CheckFileExists()
        {
            string filename = @"c:\tmp\MyService.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.Create(filename);
            }

            return filename;
        }

    }
```

Comment: It'd help if you provided a stack trace from the NullReferenceException

Comment: Here it is from event viewer: https://pastebin.com/dpRbxa1A

Comment: Did you check args?

Comment: I didn't put any args there. It works without windows service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Does ServiceBase inherite from Program ?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Nope. It is working without windows service.

Comment: @KubaDo Nope. Inherit from System.ServiceProcess

Comment: The problem lies in this code: Program.BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run but this code runs well without window service.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find the NullReferene by code. But you can make it debuggable with the following approach:

```
var s1 = new TestService();
if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
    ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] { s1 }); // when running as service
else
{
    s1.Start(args); // when running as console
    Console.ReadLine();
    s1.Stop();
}
```

this will start as windows service or console application.

Put this code to the `Program.Main` method and run under debug.

PS there is [Topshelf library](http://topshelf-project.com) also that can deal this stuff for you (run application as service or console).

PPS seems that you will need to add `public void TestService.Start` method to make this `UserInteractive` approach works:

```
public class TestService : ServiceBase
{
  // existing code

  public void Start(string[] args)
  {
    OnStart(args);
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
    OnStop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Protected method is inaccessible due to its protection level. Can't seem to change to public.

Comment: @Foong You are right, new public methods should be added. I've updated the answer.